# Classic ASP Logout Process

Tags: session, asp-classic, logout

I'm working on a web application developed classic asp. It has logout button on the top menu which basically does the following actions

1. Session.Abandon()
2. Redirect to Index.asp, where users can login again.

After logging off users return to index.asp. But if users click back button the browser, they go to previous page. I don't want this to happen. I want a message saying that they are already logged off.I have implemented following steps

1.Add `Response.Expires=-1` and `Response.CacheControl="no-cache"` at the top of each page. 
2.On each page i'm checking session object to see it is not empty. If empty i'm creating a message saying that they are already logged off and need to log in again.

Now when users click back button after logging off, instead off showing logged out message, i get "Web page expired" message on IE8. I see the same behavior when users click back button on some page while logged in.

Any ideas how i can implement this better.

Thanks.

Comment: "Web page expired" and similar messages indicate, that the user went back to a page which was a result of a POST and the browsers assume that the page state has already changed or that re-posting the original request may cause problems in the web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop users pressing back. A common scenario to work around this is that POSTs target a server page that displays no output but redirects to a new location instead (where the results can be seen).

Answer (score 1):

There are additional non caching declarations that sometimes help:

```
Response.Expires = 0
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
```

I did read some time ago (hence inability to find link) that setting an expires to -1 can cause some browser to ignore it rather than have it expire immediately.

Even adding these extra cache controls won't stop some browsers from caching some things some of the time. FF quite often ignores a forced cache reload by the user, so you are in the browser makes hands to a certain extent.

Regarding your "Web page expired" message, this is (as mentioned) the result of the browser trying to stop you from resubmitting POST data (and potentially duplicating what you last did).  The best way to get around this, and solve a number of other common UI issues on forms is to POST back to the same page, then if/when the action is completed, using a response.redirect to the same page, maybe with a URL encoded message to say "all done successfully".  This allows your users to refresh and helps with the back button issue as most browsers now don't store properly redirected pages in their history.